# Faking the req.host value on express

Tags: node.js, express, routes, cname

My web application manage user's profile this way:

```
username.mywebsite.com
```

I manage this with a subdomain express module and it works fine. (https://www.npmjs.org/package/subdomain)

```
var subdomain = '/subdomain/:profileurl';
app.get(subdomain+'/user-home', main.isThisProfileExist, main.getHome);
app.get(subdomain+'/user-info', main.isThisProfileExist, main.getInfo);
app.get(subdomain+'/user-data', main.isThisProfileExist, main.getData);
...
```

However few users have the rights to link their profile with their **custom domain name** (CNAME), and this is where my problem start : I cant find a way for my express routes to work. So I was thinking about a way to fake the req.host value of expressjs. But I don't think it is the best way to proceed.

For example the user has added this CNAME record for his domain name:

```
customdomain.com    CNAME    username.mywebsite.com
```

But in express I will get the req.host value:

```
customdomain.com
```

It's logic but it doesn't fit my need for this case because I have no way to know which profile is targeted...

Have you got any idea to help me out ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want your users to have to tell you what their customised CNAME is, you can do a DNS lookup yourself on the host that you receive.

Something like:

```
var dns = require('dns');
var domains = dns.resolveCname(req.host);
```

You can easily add this as your own middleware using connect:

```
app.use(myCustomDomainLookup());
```

An implementation in a middleware module might be something like this:

```
var dns = require('dns');

module.exports = function () {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        if (!recognisedSubdomain(req.host)) {
            var domains = dns.resolveCname(req.host);
            var validProfiles = domains.map(main.ifThisProfileExists);
            req._profile = validProfiles[0]; // Picking first valid profile
        }
        next();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

Adding code from comment here for clarity.

To integrate with your subdomain middleware, you'll need to override req.host.  This means your middleware will need to be `use`d *before* the subdomain middleware.

You should be able to adapt the above 'if' block as follows:

```
if (!recognisedSubdomain(req.host)) {
    var domains = dns.resolveCname(req.host);
    req.host = domains[0];
}
```

Since documentation for resolveCname indicates a list of domains can be returned, you'll have to decide what you want to do if more than one is returned.

Comment: Thank you! Does setting req._profile var will allow my subdomains routes to work ? Your solution works for my subdomain (ex: username.mywebsite.com, it return me the url of my EB instance, but return nothing when I'm on the custom domain name which target the subdomain username.mywebsite.com). Any idea ?

Comment: No, as-is the req._profile is there for you to choose what to do with.

If you want it to integrate with your subdomain middleware, you could probably do this within the if block, at the end:

    req.host = domains[0];

I don't know if mapping a host to multiple CNAMEs is legal - it seems weird.  But dns.resolveCname is documented to return a list so you'll have to figure out what you want to do if there is more than one domain returned.

Comment: To answer the second question in your comment, you should try checking what exact lookup you are performing with dns.resolveCname - perhaps use console.log(req.host) on the line before it.  Then also add a console.log(domains); on the line afterwards to see exactly what the result is.

If you're getting nothing returned, then I would guess that surely your DNS server can't find any entry for the custom domain.  Maybe the record hasn't propagated yet?

Comment: Finally for for security reason I ask the user to type his custom domain name and I check it in a middleware. It works good and prevent unauthorized user to use their custom domain. :) Thank you so much Rajit!